# Chrome extension communicates with a web page through message passing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

we have a JSP page in a servlet and we have developed a google chrome extension in client side. we want to communicate with the extension through the JSP or html. as we have searched, there should be a background.js and a content script. we put the background.js inside the extension folder and we register it in chrome. then as we put the content script alongside the JSP or external web page, these two pages can not interact.
this is the code of background.js:

```
alert("hey back");
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function (port) {
    port.postMessageExternal({ greeting: "hey" });
    port.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (message, sender) {
        if (message.greeting == "salam") {
            alert("message from content: " + message.greeting);
            port.postMessageExternal({ greeting: "H R U?" });
        }
        else if (message.greeting == "khobam") {
            alert("message from content: " + message.greeting);
        }
        else {
            alert("background did not receive salam");
        }
    });
});
```

this is the manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "msg-test",
    "description": "message test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
    ],
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "externally_connectable": {
        "ids":["*"],
        "matches": ["file:///C:/Users/h.aghajani/Desktop/b.html"],
        "accept_tls_channel_id":true
    }
}
```

this is the content script:

```
alert("hey content");
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "mycontentscript" });
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
    if (message.greeting == "hey") {
        alert("message from background: " + message.greeting);
        port.postMessage({ greeting: "salam" });
    }
    else if (message.greeting == "H R U?") {
        alert("message from background: " + message.greeting);
        port.postMessage({ greeting: "khobam" });
    }
    else {
        alert("content did not receive hello");
        port.postMessage({ greeting: "no salam" });
    }
});
```

there are some problems:

1. it doesn't work at all. where is the problem? in fact how can we call a
   background script from an external web page?
2. Besides, if we put the content script in the extension folder, whenever the browser works offline (without internet connection), the background and content script can not talk properly.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a content script unless it's [defined as one](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Judging by `externallyConnectable` you want to send the message [from a web page script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) but I don't see anywhere in the code how exactly it is executed. Maybe you can link the entire extension on github or something like tinyurl.com?

Comment: I have the same problem. This is a long lived message passing communication between a chrome extension and an external web page. Chrome did not provide any suitable documentation with examples!!!

Comment: Dear @wOxxOm, you mean having a content and background js in not enough. what modules do we need else? could you tell us?

Comment: we call the content.js in html, as : <script src="content.js"/> when we load this html, the only thing w see is the alert of content script.

Comment: You should register your content script in `manifest.json`. [Relevant link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)

Comment: @Bwaxxlo, it's not a content script. They use it from an external web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm From the original question, it sounds like that's what he needs

Comment: @Bwaxxlo, that's an alternative method indeed, but without seeing what exactly they need to do it might not be the best as content script don't have direct access to page variables.

Answer (score 0):

First off, never use `alert` for debugging purposes. Never. Simply forget it.

Use `console.log` or the actual [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). In order to debug the background page of an extension enable the `[x] developer mode` checkbox on the top of `chrome://extensions` page.

1. > we call the content.js in html, as : `<script src="content.js"/>`

   This is invalid HTML, the `script` tag isn't a void (self closing) element, so the correct syntax is:

   ```html
   <script src="content.js"></script>
   ```
2. As you can see on `chrome://extensions` page the extension has an error that `file://` scheme is not permitted in `"externally_connectable"`. Setup a local web server and make it serve the test files. Also you don't need `"ids":["*"]` as it's only used for communicating from other extensions/apps, not web pages.

   ```
   "externally_connectable": {
       "matches": ["http://localhost/test.html"],
       "accept_tls_channel_id":true
   },
   ```
3. Now at last the page script, misleadingly named as `content.js`, is loaded and displays an error in the console that `chrome.runtime.connect` should specify the extension ID as the first parameter as per the documentation so that Chrome would know where to send the message.

   ```
   var port = chrome.runtime.connect("qwertyuiopasdfghjkl", { name: "mycontentscript" });
   ```

   replace `qwertyuiopasdfghjkl` with your extension's ID as seen on `chrome://extensions` page when the `[x] developer mode` checkbox is enabled on the top.
4. Now let's look at the background script:

   There's no such thing in Chrome API as `postMessageExternal`, just use `postMessage`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I did the same as you say and in console log, I can see following messages: 1) "hey content", 2) "message from background hey". As you can see, in my example I want the background and the test.html to talk to each other in several iterations (i expect to see messages "salam", "khobam", "H R U" either). In fact the original test.html wants to talk to the background via AJAX. for this purpose (in order to make more the interaction between html and background other than once) what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Moreover through your helpful comments I can debug the test.html Javascript, but how can I go to the extension Java script ( background.js) through debugging?

Comment: That's an easily googlable question, moreover my answer already mentions it.

Comment: The secret sauce that nobody is mentioning- Maybe it is being inferred, but the html has to be loaded from your localhost (it could be internet) & JavaScript called. You can put it in the manifest and the background.js will run - but without the web page being loaded, it won't work. To call your webpage in the background run it in an iframe, in your case, b.html. Like this:  <script src="background.js"></script>
      <iframe src="http://www.myurl.com/helloworld.html"></iframe> then make helloworld load your content.js which has your comms.This will save at least a few people visiting.

Comment: @wOxxOm Why should you never use alerts for debugging?  In many cases, using an alert is undesirable (for locking up the page). But in cases where you want to alert the user/developer of a rare occurrence I find it to be useful.

Comment: @Ribo, the advice may seem far-fetched, but a frighteningly big percentage of people don't know there's a convenient built-in debugger in the browser with step-by-step execution, using which they can solve 99% of their problems quickly in a matter of seconds or minutes instead of awkwardly stumbling through alert dialogs, adding/removing them, repeating the process semi-randomly - this is what people do, yes.